# right arrow key is not working in WPF Devepress TextEdit

Tags: datagrid

<dxe:TextEdit VerticalAlignment="Center" MaskType="RegEx"   DisplayFormatString="HH:mm:ss"
EditMode="InplaceActive"  Mask="([0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]"
EditValue="{Binding RowData.Row.StartTime, NotifyOnValidationError=true,Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=true}"
NullText="hh:mm:ss">
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
<ei:KeyTrigger Key="Enter" FiredOn="KeyDown" ActiveOnFocus="True" >
<i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.KeyDownCommand,ElementName=wndNTCreateGroup}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=gridDate}" />
</ei:KeyTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
</dxe:TextEdit>

An output in  which the left arrow key will work